# Copy Folder Content From one Branch to Another

Tags: git

I'm trying to copy content of a specific folder from one branch to another using `git checkout` but it's copying the folder and its content. I only want to copy the content of folder.

The command that I'm using:

```bash
git checkout origin/TestBranch -- TestToCopy
```

The branch `TestBranch` has a folder called `TestToCopy`. I want to copy only its content. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I don't understand. What does it mean to copy "only the content"? What are the current files in your working tree and what is the expected directory structure?

Comment: It seems like you don't know that **branches** are. A **branch** is a pointer to a blob. If you wish to have multiple branches point to the same blob, you can do so by creating a new branch (or delete an existing branch and then create one with the same name). Does this make sense?

Comment: After it shows up inside of the folder, just move it to where you want it, and then commit.

Comment: @knittl , I have branch1 that have multiple folder, one of them called TestToCopy, I created branch2 and Im trying to copy only the content of folder TestToCopy to it, using the command above , I tried "TestToCope/* and testToCopy/." but nothing worked

Comment: @Caleb , of course I know what branch means, I working on a CI that create another and emtpy branch and copy only the content of the folder TestToCopy

Comment: @OubaydaSamrouth so you want to move the content of the folder out of the folder to the top level of your tree?

Comment: @knittl yes, thats what im trying to do , copying the content of a folder in branch1, to the root folder of branch2

Comment: *Branches* don't have root folders, branches point to a commit and a commit has a tree

Comment: @OubaydaSamrouth You just argued that you *do* know what branches are, while simultaneously demonstrating that you *do not*. Please rephrase your question once you figure out what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @knittl Im creating an orphan branch and I'm deleting everything from it and copy what I said above that why I said root folder

Comment: @OubaydaSamrouth there already is an answer. Does it not answer your question/solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a simple two-step command:

```
git checkout origin/TestBranch -- TestToCopy && git mv TestToCopy/* TestToCopy/.* .
```

Specifying both `*` and `.*` makes sure that hidden files are moved too.

Comment: Good Idea,  I tried on my CI (ubuntu) and on the git bash it worked perefectly, but on the powershell didn't, simple and easy thanks for the help

Comment: git mv didn't work on the config files/folder (there name start with dot like .gitignore) I need to specify the the file in the path to be able to move it the start * workd only on the files that does not start with dot , any idea for this one ?

Comment: @OubaydaSamrouth whoops, looks like `git mv` cannot handle wildcards, so you need your shell do that. Find my updated answer.

Comment: I did: 
`$ git mv TestToCopy/.* .`

result: 
`fatal: '..' is outside repository at 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Git/TestGit'`

Comment: @OubaydaSamrouth is the folder inside your repository? Which shell are you using? What does `echo TestToCopy/.*` print?

Comment: it gave me all the files + `TestToCopy/..` thats why it causing this error, is there any way to execlude `TestToCopy/..` ?

Comment: @OubaydaSamrouth oh, I see. `bash` excludes `..`, but `dash` (and perhaps others) include `..` – `git mv -k` will skip errors